# I am stuck with a Query in Sql Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, group-by

hi i want to write a query but i don't understand how to solve it

```
ID  Category    Volume
1   FFP         157
1   RBCD        279
2   FFP         146
2   PLT         70
2   RBCD        280
3   FFP         145
3   PLT         67
3   RBCD        275
4   FFP         148
4   RBCD        280
```

my result should be like this

```
ID  Category1   Volume1 Category2   Volume2 Category3   Volume3
1   FFP         157    RBCD          279    NULL        NULL
2   FFP         146    RBCD          280    PLT         70
3   FFP         145    RBCD          275    PLT         67
4   FFP         148    RBCD          280    NULL        NULL
```

By using **Juergen D**  i am getting like this

```
ID  Category1   volume1     Category2   volume2 Category3   Volume3
1   FFP         157         NULL        NULL    NULL        Null
1   NULL        NULL        RBCD        279     NULL        Null
2   FFP         146         NULL        NULL    NULL        Null
2   NULL        NULL        RBCD        280     NULL        Null
2   NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL    PLT         70
3   FFP         145         NULL        NULL    NULL        Null
3   NULL        NULL        RBCD        275     NULL        Null
3   NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL    PLT         67
4   FFP         148         NULL        NULL    NULL        Null
4   NULL        NULL        RBCD        280     NULL        Null
```

Anybody give me any idea how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id,
       min(case when Category = 'FFP' then Category end) as Category1,
       sum(case when Category = 'FFP' then Volume end) as Volume1,
       min(case when Category = 'RBCD' then Category end) as Category2,
       sum(case when Category = 'RBCD' then Volume end) as Volume2,
       min(case when Category = 'PLT' then Category end) as Category3,
       sum(case when Category = 'PLT' then Volume end) as Volume3
from your_table
GROUP BY id
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c8a13/7)

Comment: i will check and tell you

Comment: Juergen d it is not working.ok see i update my question with your Query result

Comment: juergen d help me based on this Question

Comment: since I did not solve the issue you better remove the checkmark.